# how to convert the given time into milliseconds if time format is given in 7 Jan 2016 18:03:32 +0200

Tags: java

I have been trying to convert the below time to milliseconds but i was unable to do so.This is my time format. Can anyone help me? I tried the following code i got the time in milliseconds only for **"7 Jan 2016 18:03:32"**.

> eg: 7 Jan 2016 18:03:32 +0200

My code is like this.

```
  if(requiredOnlyDate.find()){


     String dateWithTime=requiredOnlyDate.group();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
     String dateInString =dateWithTime ;

     Date   date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
     System.out.println(date.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: Read the documentation of SimpleDateFormat. Lowercase `hh` stands for twelve-hour time (values 1-12) and you're trying to parse 24 hour time, so you should use `HH`. Also when you try to parse time zone information (the `+0200` part) you also need to have that in your SimpleDateFormat pattern.

Comment: I used below line it worked fine for me now.Thanks anyways.    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

Answer (score 0):

The Date format need to be used should match the Date String you want to parse.

First of all you are parsing a 24 hour Date system `(18:03:02)`, so in place of `hh` please use `HH`.

Also `+0200` represent time zone, so you have to include `Z` in the Date format.

So your final Date Format will be

```
String dateWithTime=requiredOnlyDate.group();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
...//do whatever you want
```

Please let me know, if it helps.

Comment: Does this worked ? I think "+Z" should be "Z" isn't it ? Otherwise it will give exception.

Comment: yeah it works....i tried that and i posted that in the comment as well.Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. In there it uses time format as **"`dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`"** it works find. I checked on **"`dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +SSS`"** this format also worked on String to date transformation.

```
        String dateWithTime = "7 Jan 2016 18:03:32 +0200";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        String dateInString = dateWithTime;

        Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

**Updated**

Comment: the hour is 24 hour based system and you are using `hh` which is for 12 hour based system. Will it work??